# Flag resolved comments?

Tags: discussion

Comments can be invaluable in improving questions and answers.  They can also lock them down as one becomes reluctant to edit in it ways that would make the comments meaningless.

If a comment, or a long chain of comments, brings up a good point, inspires an edit, and becomes meaningless to the current post is it appropriate to flag it? Say after soliciting, and allowing time for, a response to the edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comments of the kind you describe can be flagged as **obsolete.**

Use this when the comment chain is completely incorporated in the change made to the post.  Consider refraining from flagging when there are other insights in the comment chain (not incorporated into the post) that might be valuable to someone else.